# Cannot load a shapefile in R "Error: no features found"

Tags: r, gdal, shapefile, rgdal

I'm trying to read the shapefile that you can download with this [url](http://www6.gipuzkoa.eus/CATASTRO/Planos/ZIP-A098.zip).

I have a code similar to the next one to download automatically the files:

```
library("raster")}
url<-"http://www6.gipuzkoa.eus/CATASTRO/Planos/ZIP-A098.zip"
downloader::download(url, dest=paste0(getwd(),"/","my_file.zip"), mode="wb",quiet=T)

zipped_shape_names<-c("098_HELBIDE_SHP/ATRIBUTOAK-A098.cpg","098_HELBIDE_SHP/ATRIBUTOAK-A098.dbf","098_HELBIDE_SHP/ATRIBUTOAK-A098.shp","098_HELBIDE_SHP/ATRIBUTOAK-A098.shx")

unzip("my_file.zip", files=zipped_shape_names)
my_shape<-raster::shapefile("098_HELBIDE_SHP/ATRIBUTOAK-A098.shp")
```

But what I obtain is the following error:

```
Error in rgdal::readOGR(dirname(x), fn, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors,  : 
  no features found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In .local(x, ...) : .prj file is missing
2: In ogrFIDs(dsn = dsn, layer = layer) : no features found
```

You can access to the original web page by this [link](http://www6.gipuzkoa.eus/CATASTRO/map.htm?id=98&idioma=esp) and pressing "Descargar planos"

I don't have this problem with others areas, just with this and another one, but I don't know what is happening with this specific area.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: apparently it's an incomplete shapefile. Can you load it in another GIS software tool?

Comment: I loaded the shape in Q-gis. There are just no features in the shapefile (it's empty, no data), the gdal error message is quite clear.

Comment: You also get the warning that your projection file is missing - this should be added to get the correct geo reference (e.g. WGS84 or metrical projection?) of the shapefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is quite clear. `no features found` means that your shapefile is empty. You can check this in multiple ways.

One is to add your shapefile in Q-Gis or any other GIS-software tool. In the case of Q-GIS your shapefile will pop-up in the layers pane, but you won't see any features.

It is also possible to check the `.dbf` file in R:

```
library(foreign)
read.dbf("098_HELBIDE_SHP/ATRIBUTOAK-A098.dbf")
```

The `.dbf` should contain as many rows as there are features. In your case `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler code would be

```
library(raster)
url<-"http://www6.gipuzkoa.eus/CATASTRO/Planos/ZIP-A098.zip"
download.file(url, dest="my_file.zip")
unzip("my_file.zip")   
s <- raster::shapefile("098_HELBIDE_SHP/ATRIBUTOAK-A098.shp")
```

Clearly that file is empty. However, it works for this file:

```
s <-raster::shapefile("098_LANDALUR_SHP/LANDALUR-PARTZELAK-A098.shp")
```

Comment: I don't want to unzip all the folder, that's the reason why I create a varible calle `zipped_shape_names`